# 97% range around the mean

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am doing some industry work in public transport and we are reviewing the time tables. To do this we are extracting data from a real time information system we have for the last 12 months.

We are looking at the difference between the time the bus arrives at timing points and the scheduled time and taking the mean of these differences. However, we want more information about the range of the data before we make any decisions on how much to change the timetable by.

We have thought about looking at the range but then thought it would be better to look at the range that say 95% of the data falls within.

Would you suggest that the data follows a normal distribution and we can look at the standard deviation to get the range that 95% of the data falls within (2 standard deviations above and below the mean).

If you have any other statistics that would be good to look at please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that your data follows a normal distribution, particularly out on the tails where you are interested.  You can imagine that the dispersion in most bus arrival times are because of variation in time waiting for red lights, passengers to load, etc.  There will be a most common arrival time and the distribution near that may be rather symmetric, but very few if any buses will arrive very much before it while some will be quite late.  You can compute the standard deviation, but it will probably be more influenced by the few very late buses than by normal activity.

Just making up some data, suppose you have $100$ arrival times. $10$ of them are $2$ minutes before the most common, $20$ are $1$ minute before, $35$ are at the most common, $20$ are $1$ minute after, $10$ are $2$ minutes after, and you have one each of $5,8,10,15,30$ minutes after.  The mean is only $0.69$ minutes after the most common, so you represent the most common reasonably well.  The standard deviation is $3.75$, so no bus is even $1\sigma $ early and $95\%$ fall within $\pm 1 \sigma$ instead of $68\%$ with the normal distribution. If the long delays are even longer, the mean will stop representing "normal behavior".

I would suggest that a more useful statistic would be the fraction of time that you are more than $x$ minutes late (say $3$ to $5$, but that is dependent on how late makes your passengers upset) then what fraction you are more than $2x, 3x$, etc.  I would suggest that reducing the fraction of the time you are $2$ minutes late will do less to make your public happy than eliminating the $30$ minute delay.  Of course, eliminating the one big event is hard to do, and focusing on that makes year to year comparisons very noisy.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll guess from your question that you hope to change the published timetable so it agrees more closely with reality (as opposed to making changes to the system itself).

This isn’t my professional area, but my first thought would be that identifying and improving some summary statistic of the past discrepancies, like range, mean, or width of a percentile-based interval isn’t what you need.

I’d ask “What do I hope to improve?” and then compare that under the current timetable (using the historical data) to the same thing under various alternate timetables. The number of data points isn’t in the billions, so computationally, it’s feasible to evaluate even weird measures against many alternatives using all the data.

Perhaps you want to minimize the number of people per week (if you have passenger-count data; or number of minutes in the day if not, either of which might be weighted by when on-timeness is likely most critical to passengers, if not) who have to wait - I don’t know - either more than five minutes or more than half the time to the next listed arrival time.

The armchair psychologist in me thinks (for buses and subways, not commuter trains) people don’t care about the timetable until they’ve been waiting several minutes or some length of time approaching the frequency of arrivals on the line.

With that in mind, I think I would brainstorm a variety of measurables like the percent or raw number of printed arrival times where a transport (the scheduled one or a previous late one) arrived on the line within the next N minutes, where N is max(4,half the interval between arrivals on the line at that time of the day/week) - maybe separately measured on weekdays and weekends (maybe extra-weighted on Friday afternoons...), and see how they would change under different schedules. It’s probably a little, but not a lot, harder to do this than to work with plain averages and intervals.

Although “our timetables are nearly correct” might be a good goal for PR (and possibly for industry benchmarking), you may also want to aim for “our timetables don’t frustrate customers,” even if the latter is trickier to nail down.

My $2.75 worth, or whatever a ticket costs.